# trouble creating menu with fade-in and fade out of images effect

Tags: jquery, css, gsap

I am a newbie web designer. I am trying to make a menu where when i hover over a menu item on right the images on left fade out and the other image fades in. I also want the fade in and out with zoom in and zoom out effect, much like the menu from [the website][1] (see the menu in the top right).

Here is my version but its a work-in-progress

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #111111;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.menu a:hover {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- leftSide -->
  <div class="left">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/15792501/pexels-photo-15792501.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2') no-repeat center center / cover;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/16375253/pexels-photo-16375253.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2') no-repeat center center / cover;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/14917839/pexels-photo-14917839.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2') no-repeat center center / cover;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/15413559/pexels-photo-15413559.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2') no-repeat center center / cover;"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="right">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can simplify the code a bit so that hovering over a link will transition in the associated image and transition out the previous image.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%;
  background-color: #111;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.menu a:hover {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menu span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}

.menu a:not(:hover) img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15792501/pexels-photo-15792501.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Home
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/16375253/pexels-photo-16375253.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> About Us
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14917839/pexels-photo-14917839.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Services
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15413559/pexels-photo-15413559.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Contact Us
  </a>
</div>
```

In the website you linked though, the last-hovered image stays active. We'd need to use JavaScript to mark the active item to keep the associated image active:

```js
document
  .querySelector('.menu')
  // Listen for when the mouse hovers a child element.
  .addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target, currentTarget }) => {
    // Get the hovering element, if it is a `<a>` element and not
    // marked as active:
    const hovering = target.matches('a') ? target : target.closest('a');
    if (hovering && !hovering.matches('.active')) {
      // Remove the previously marked active element.
      currentTarget.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
      // Add the active mark to this element.
      hovering.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%;
  background-color: #111;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu a {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.menu a:hover {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menu span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}

.menu a:not(.active) img {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15792501/pexels-photo-15792501.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Home
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/16375253/pexels-photo-16375253.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> About Us
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14917839/pexels-photo-14917839.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Services
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15413559/pexels-photo-15413559.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2" /></span> Contact Us
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. could you help me with a default image . where if not hovered it shows.. i mean black blank does not look good... thanks